# pom.xml grunt task error Failed to run task (com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven)

Tags: java, maven, gruntjs, pom.xml

I have a grunt task in my pom xml which works fine. I am trying to build and it builds correctly. Then I change the argument to use another task it gives error

```
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <!-- optional: default phase is "generate-resources" -->
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>grunt build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>grunt</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
        ------------------> <arguments>prodBuild</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>...
```

When I change prodBuild to another task say prodBuild2 that I have it get the following error. The grunt task prodBuild and prodBuild2 are available in the grunt file.

```
Failed to run task (com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:grunt:grunt build 2:generate-resources)

org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Failed to run task
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.AbstractFrontendMojo.execute(AbstractFrontendMojo.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1362)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1360)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
Caused by: com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.TaskRunnerException: 'grunt devRun' failed.
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.NodeTaskExecutor.execute(NodeTaskExecutor.java:63)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.GruntMojo.execute(GruntMojo.java:64)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.AbstractFrontendMojo.execute(AbstractFrontendMojo.java:94)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.ProcessExecutionException: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.ProcessExecutor.execute(ProcessExecutor.java:82)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.ProcessExecutor.executeAndRedirectOutput(ProcessExecutor.java:64)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.NodeExecutor.executeAndRedirectOutput(NodeExecutor.java:29)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.NodeTaskExecutor.execute(NodeTaskExecutor.java:58)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.ProcessExecutor.execute(ProcessExecutor.java:74)
    ... 37 more
```

Comment: any update on this ?